# DELETE localhost/ API not found, MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I made a web API from Entity framework and then I tried to make a DELETE call so I can delete stuff from my jquery datatable through AJAX. I'm getting an error that DELETE localhost/ api is not found. Here is my code.

```
    @section scripts{
<script>
$(document).ready( function () {
    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
    $("#myTable .js-delete").on("click", function () {
        var button = $(this);
        //bootbox.confirm("Do you want to delete this movie?", function (result) {
            //if (result) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/api/FriendApi/" + button.attr("data-friend-id"),
                    method: "DELETE",
                    success: function () {
                        table.row(button.parents("tr")).remove().draw();
                    }
                });
            //}
        //});
    })
} );
</script>
    }
```

This is my web api

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

ApiController

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using WebApplication2.Models;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class FriendApiController : ApiController
    {
        private FriendContext db = new FriendContext();

        // GET: api/FriendApi
        public IQueryable<FriendModel> Getfriends()
        {
            return db.friends;
        }

        // GET: api/FriendApi/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(FriendModel))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetFriendModel(int id)
        {
            FriendModel friendModel = db.friends.Find(id);
            if (friendModel == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(friendModel);
        }

        // PUT: api/FriendApi/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
        public IHttpActionResult PutFriendModel(int id, FriendModel friendModel)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != friendModel.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.Entry(friendModel).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!FriendModelExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }

        // POST: api/FriendApi
        [ResponseType(typeof(FriendModel))]
        public IHttpActionResult PostFriendModel(FriendModel friendModel)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.friends.Add(friendModel);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = friendModel.Id }, friendModel);
        }

        // DELETE: api/FriendApi/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(FriendModel))]
        [Route("FriendModel/{id}")]
        public IHttpActionResult DeleteFriendModel(int id)
        {
            FriendModel friendModel = db.friends.Find(id);
            if (friendModel == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            db.friends.Remove(friendModel);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return Ok(friendModel);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private bool FriendModelExists(int id)
        {
            return db.friends.Count(e => e.Id == id) > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically this is my WebApi and the Api I made myself (in this case I used Entity's framework Api). I wrote the same code like a week ago and it worked but now it doesn't work. I have no clue why.

Comment: please show your web api

Comment: Can you please post your controller action?

Comment: can you please show the api controller?

Comment: I'll never understand people asking for the same things (all at least 1 minute apart). 3 comments asking for the OP to post the API, really? It only needs saying once.

Comment: Added, sorry for not putting it. First time asking on stackoverflow

Comment: @AnthinoRusso - you have no `[HttpDelete]` attribute, and your URL is entirely wrong.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ you need to understand *concurrency* first. Many people can write the same comment but only hit `post` minutes apart. There are *no* notifications for new comments. The same as a database really

Comment: Exactly, if it's minutes apart that gives ample time to have seen somebody else post it.

Comment: @JayMee no it doesn't. Just like a database and optimistic concurrency. When I posted my comment the page refreshed with 4 more that I didn't see when I started writing.

Comment: The page doesn't refresh when you post a comment, it's done with ajax.

Comment: Just inserted [HttpDelete] above my action and yet, this is what I get
DELETE http://localhost:63055/api/FriendApi/1 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @AnthinoRusso - that's half the problem,I imagine it's still failing to route your request successfully. The URL doesn't match.

Comment: @JayMee Any idea how to match the URL?

Comment: I'd read up on routing if I were you, I can tell you this once but you won't know how I got to the answer so might get stuck the next time you write an action: `api/FriendApi/DeleteFriendModel/{id}` (that's *if* you've removed your route attribute)

Comment: Actually solved it. Looks like I forgot to link the new api in Global.asax. Thanks tho

Answer (score 2):

Your C# code has:

```
[Route("FriendModel/{id}")]
```

But your script is requesting:

```
DELETE /api/FriendApi/{id}
```

Spot the difference!

Comment: I removed [Route("FriendModel/{id}")], still have the same problem. So you suggest that in my route I should add /api/ infront?